# "Every thing result as I like" why it's not "results" which I was expecting?

Tags: grammar

Here is the original quote from The Discourses of Epictetus translated by George Long:

> But, you say, I would have everything result just as I like, and in whatever way I like.

In grammar it is said that everything should be treated as singular so I was expecting results instead of result. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing the fact that _I would have everything result as I like_ means the same as _I would like everything to result (turn out) as I like_, so _result_ is in the infinitive form.

Answer (score 2):

**Result** is not conjugated because it is not the main verb of the clause.  Look at the sentence again; the speaker is saying "I **would have** everything *result*..."

When you use a modal like *would*, or a construction like "have someone " you don't conjugate the following verb.  For example,

- He **paints** the house.
- She **has** him *paint* the house.
- She **would** *have* him *paint* the house.

Reference: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/modal-verbs/

Comment: Thanks. This construct or pattern with "would have" and even "would" in general are very alian to me as a non native English learner. May be I need to get used to it.

Comment: English has many different verbal constructions (which makes up for the lack of tenses as found in some other languages). But however complicated the contruction ,only the first verb in the construction can take the tense form in _-s_: all following verbs will either be a participle (_is paint**ing**, _has paint**ed**_, _is paint**ed**_) or the base form. You can get constructions as complicated as _it would have been going to have been sold_, but nothing but the first verb can be tensed (and in this case the first verb is the modal _would_, which does not have an _-s_ form).